# several list items with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, list

can somebody explain why this is not working?

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cbF2pZ97)

I am trying to have several list items with a jquery function that makes them slideUp or slideDown, depending on which item you click. I want only on "inner" list at a time.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FpLTj/1/

Comment: Never use only pastebin, still post relevant code here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any script tag with attribute src specified will strip out all js code embeded inside own script. That means, you should use this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () { //wait for DOM ready
    $("ul > li").has("> ul").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find("> ul").slideToggle();
        $(this).siblings("li").find("> ul").slideUp();
    });
    $("ul > li").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good catch - I didn't even notice this. `+1`

Comment: yeah the Thing is it works perfectly fine in jsfiddle but not as a file on my local Computer, even preloading the jquery didn't Change that

Comment: Try to anticipate question like this one: Have you got any error in console?

Comment: which console do you mean?

Comment: the debug console in your browser, usually opened using F12 key